# AJAX response returns valid JSON, console logs undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

So I have a peculiar issue with my AJAX request. When I make the request, I can click on the network tab and see the response, which is valid JSON. But when I try to use that data in my success function of the ajax call, it returns undefined. I'll post some pics of my console and network tab and some code.

[image: Console]

[image: network]

And at last my code:

```
getWebinars: function (from, to, credential) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'endpoint',
        data: {
                     from: from,
                     to: to,
                     credential: credential
        },
        success: function (reply, status, xhr) {

            console.log(reply);
            var html = '<select class="webinars" multiple>';
            for(var webinar_id in reply.list) {
                html+=  '<option value="' + webinar_id + '">' + reply.list[webinar_id] + '</option>';
            }

            html+= '</select>';

             $('.modal-body').append(html);
        }
    });
}
```

I can't figure out for the life of me what the issue is here. I have tried everything I can think of. Logging the xhr, logging the responseJSON, setting the datatype to json. It's a simple get request and it's working, but the console doesn't seem to think so. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does your log statement show? Also might want to add `dataType:'json'` to options

Comment: I've tried that as well. No go. When I log the xhr, it adds a value of responseJSON: undefined.

Comment: so where you have `console.log(reply);` it shows `undefined`? Very strange

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty bizarre. All in all, everything LOOKS fine. Weird thing is I even took the response, put it in a json file and uploaded it and still got the same thing.

Comment: You sure only one request is made? Perhaps one has data, other doesn't and throws error?

Comment: Positive. It's triggered on a button click, so it definitely only fires once. I am going to double double check this right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, so I figured this one out, sort of. I should say "I fixed it" I still don't know why it did what it did. For whatever reason, jQuery was executing the success callback well before the request was complete, hence my undefined issue. I switched it over to good ol' vanilla javascript and it worked fine. As to why it happened with jquery, I don't have an answer for that. Hopefully this will help others out.

Comment: are you sure you didn't simplify the example code by converting `success: successFunc()` to `success: function () {}`? the former would produce the results you are seeing, the latter wouldn't.

Comment: Yeah, positive. The code I pasted in is verbatim the code from my script. I noticed in my console that it consoles undefined the second I hit the button to fire the ajax call. So I looked in the network tab and the console and it was logging undefined before the request completed in the network tab. Very strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Your root cause is you don't mention dataType:'JSON' as parameter of your AJAX request.
So there is two ways to resolve your problem.
1.Add dataType parameter.
2.Parse the returned result using jQuery.parseJSON().

Solution 1

```js
url: 'endpoint',
data: {
       from: from,
       to: to,
       credential: credential
        },
dataType:'text json'
```

solution 2

```js
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(reply);
alert( obj.list);
```

Comment: Already did that. It fails. Doesn't matter if datatype is there or not. If I try to parse it either way, the response is undefined, so it throws and "Unexpected character at [0] 'u'" (undefined).

Comment: cool.send me the complete response dataset ot webservice which return this .

Comment: this doesn't explain why response data is undefined

Comment: The response is undefined still. It's trying to parse a string that is not even a json string into a json object. It can't parse the word undefined, so it's back at square one.